# preupgradecheck site definition missing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, migration, upgrade

I have a missing site definition when i do a SharePoint 2007 preupgrade check, and I can't find any information on it online, nor do I know how to remove it. The details are...

name = Unknown, language = 1033, template id = 15, count = 1, status = Missing

There are no missing features, just this rogue side definition that is blocking my upgrade. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to do. I ran stsadm -o enumallwebs -databasename mydatabasename which gave me a list of all the sites and their templates.

I then matched the id (in this case 15) to the site that was using it and deleted that site since I didn't need it anymore. The preupgradecheck now throws no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft support article says this:- [The SiteDefinitionInfo rule in Pre-Upgrade Checker for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Service Pack 2 lists information about site definition templates](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954761)

Which has the following text

> Install the missing site definitions
>   in order for the content to be
>   displayed and upgraded correctly.
>   After upgrading the current farm to
>   the new version of sharepoint, any
>   sites that use one of the internal
>   site definitions will be upgraded if
>   necessary. Custom site definitions
>   will need to be upgraded using a
>   Upgrade Definition File

Comment: I understand that I need to either install the missing site definition, or remove it completely. The problem is I don't know what the site definition is; since the only detail I know is that the template id = 15. I don't know the name etc.